# vb.wpf user control event not triggered in another user control

Tags: wpf, vb.net, wpf-controls

I have an application that contains a user control (NavigationBar) with public events.  In the same application I have other user controls that use a NavigationBar and subscribe to it's events, however they are never triggered.

If I change the NavigationBar events to be "Shared", then they trigger in the user control, however since I need several instances of NavigationBar in the application, this is not possible.

Here is the NavigationBar user control event declaration
    Public Class NavigationBar

```
Public Event BeforeSaveItems As RoutedEventHandler
Protected Sub OnBeforeSaveItems(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    RaiseEvent BeforeSaveItems(sender, e)
End Sub
...
End Class
```

In the user control - here is where I subscribe to the event:

```
Public NavBarOverstock As NavigationBar
NavBarOverstock = New NavigationBar
AddHandler NavBarOverstock.BeforeSaveItems, AddressOf navBarBeforeSave

Public Sub navBarBeforeSave(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    MsgBox("overstock before save")
End Sub
```

I can interrupt the code and see that the RaiseEvent BeforeSaveItems is called, but the event is never triggered in the user control.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

-Rick

Comment: Initialize instance of  `Navigationbar` with keyword `WithEvents`. `Public WithEvents NavBarOverstock As New NavigationBar()`

Comment: Yes, I have tried that and it does not help.  It does allow you to put "Handles.BeforeSaveItems" on the Public Sub line so you don't have to use AddHandler, but no other effect.